# Sending Wav Audio File As RTP Packets

Tags: audio-streaming, rtsp, rtp

Suppose that I have an wav audio stay on my disk call it MyDummy.wav.
I want to send it to a server as an RTP Packet. But As I see there are some timing issues with RTP Packet sending  some says 20 ms etc...And how I will determine size of RTP Packet... I really can not figure out how to do many things , and  are all things necessary?

Anyone can tell as a Pseudocode how to packetize an audio file as RTP packets 
and at which timing I should send the audio or provide any sample code which I can investigate?

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at [Live555 Library](http://www.live555.com/). Start with the sample programs. Would definitely straighten out things a bit.

Comment: There is no satisfactory answer: The reference codes are ugly.None talk about timing. But thanks all..I should have chose one

Answer (score 4):

Please check out the following open source project:

http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/

It supports streaming wav audio files out of the box.

'The "LIVE555 Media Server" is a complete RTSP server application. It can stream several kinds of media file (which must be stored in the current working directory - i.e., the directory from which you launch the application - or a subdirectory.):'

- A WAV (PCM) audio file (with file name suffix ".wav")

Answer (score 3):

you should try : [**WAV-2-RTP software**](http://wav2rtp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Hippias, some of your payload related answers about the theory are described pretty well in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3952#section-3

I added Java examples below because it is fairly easy to read and verbose enough for you to follow.

Though you'd probably not want to write a wav streamer from scratch.
There is an old Java RTP library, freely available, though it's not been actively maintained for several years now: https://github.com/biasedbit/efflux

For reading and writing wav files, here is a neat tutorial: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html - earthling friendly.

Also, Columbia has some code for an RTP receiver from almost 20 years ago: [http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/teaching/ais/1998/projects/java_rtp/java/net/RTP/RTCPReceiverThread.java](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ehgs/teaching/ais/1998/projects/java_rtp/java/net/RTP/RTCPReceiverThread.java) Additionally, they have a bunch of related utilities like monitoring if you dig around in those folders.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class UdpDataReceiver implements Runnable {

    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private int port = -1;
    private DatagramSocket socket;

    public UdpDataReceiver(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
        socket.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
            System.out.println(" + Listening for UDP data on port " + port + ".");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Size of data buffer is insignificant; it just needs to be big enough to hold the UDP packet (or it will be truncated).
        byte[] data = new byte[512];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);

        String file = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            // For now we'll just dump to a file.
            file = "C:\\tmp\\" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".raw";
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            while (isRunning) {
                try {
                    socket.receive(packet);
                } catch (SocketException se) {
                    // If we're just trying to tell the socket we're done, we'll get a SocketException.
                    if (isRunning) {
                        se.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (packet.getLength() > 12) {
                    // Strip off 12 bytes of header data.
                    fos.write(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset() + 12, packet.getLength() - 12);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                convertULawFileToWav(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            System.out.println(" + Closed port " + port + " and wrote UDP packets to file: " + file);
        }
    }

    public static void convertULawFileToWav(String filename) {
        File file = new File(filename);
        if (!file.exists())
            return;
        try {
            long fileSize = file.length();
            int frameSize = 160;
            long numFrames = fileSize / frameSize;
            AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(Encoding.ULAW, 8000, 8, 1, frameSize, 50, true);
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), audioFormat, numFrames);
            AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, Type.WAVE, new File(file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, file.getAbsolutePath().length() - 3) + "wav"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // For testing...
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        UdpDataReceiver r1 = new UdpDataReceiver(65337);
        new Thread(r1).start();
        // Send data...
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        r1.stop();
    }

}
shareeditflag
```